# Avoid incorrect rounding when part of a Numpy Array is replaced

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding-error

In one part of my code I have used the following code with numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1,-8],[2,-1],[2,14]])

k=2
x = np.array([[0],[15]])       

v=np.array([[1/np.sqrt(2)],[1/np.sqrt(2)]])

temp = x - 2*v @ v.T @ x

print("temp = ",temp)
I=np.array([[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]])
print("I = ",I)

I[k-1:3,k-1:2]= temp
print("new I =",I)
```

This is the output that I see:

```
temp =  
[[-1.50000000e+01]
 [ 3.55271368e-15]]
I =  
[[0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]]
new I = 
[[  0   0]
 [  0 -14]
 [  0   0]]
```

However -1.50000000e+01  = -15 so I am not sure why this element is being replaced with -14.

Comment: not reproducible https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/AquaNutritiousMapping

Comment: Hmm, it might be important to note that my temp variable was returned from a function so those values might not be exact.

Comment: @Shree, it could be that you get float like `-1.4999998e+1`"

Comment: if you dont provide enough information to reproduce i dont think youll get the help you need :/

Comment: @OlvinRoght would that still not round to -15 in that case?

Comment: @Shreem [nope](https://repl.it/repls/HideousUsedVisitors), it will round it to -14

Comment: `int(-14.999)` its not rounding (ie `int` will `truncate`)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Is there a general method to display the rounded value of elements in arrays instead of int()?

Comment: `I[1:3,1:2]= np.round(temp)` ? (basically your np.array is dtype int ... so it will cast anything not int to int (if it cant I think it throws an error)), if you left set the dtype to float it would not try to cast to int ... but i dont know what your desired output actually is

Comment: This works, but I am working in exact values, perhaps I can calculate everything and round the final result.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I have updated it so it is reproducible

Comment: `I` is `int` dtype; any floats assigned to it will be truncated to integer.  Truncation is subject to floating point errors.

Comment: @Shree you should change `I` data type if you want to work with exat values `>>> I = I.astype(np.float)` then you don't have to worry about round.

Comment: @DishinHGoyani Ok, it seems the data type is the main issue, I will change it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I modify your code to create float dtype arrays, especially `I`:

```
In [88]: A=np.array([[1,-8],[2,-1],[2,14]], float)    ###
    ...:  
    ...: k=2 
    ...: x = np.array([[0],[15]])        
    ...:  
    ...: v=np.array([[0.70710678],[0.70710678]]) 
    ...:  
    ...: temp = x - 2*v @ v.T @ x 
    ...:  
    ...: print("temp = ",temp) 
    ...: I=np.array([[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]], float)      ####
    ...: print("I = ",I) 
    ...:  
    ...: I[k-1:3,k-1:2]= temp 
    ...: print("new I =",I)                                                                    
temp =  [[-1.49999999e+01]
 [ 5.03409456e-08]]
I =  [[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
new I = [[ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00 -1.49999999e+01]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  5.03409456e-08]]
```

`round` gives me more control than truncation:

```
In [90]: np.round(I)                                                                           
Out[90]: 
array([[  0.,   0.],
       [  0., -15.],
       [  0.,   0.]])
In [91]: I.astype(int)                                                                         
Out[91]: 
array([[  0,   0],
       [  0, -14],
       [  0,   0]])
```